# Oracle SQL using sub queries

Tags: oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm having some troubles learning sub queries. I'm trying to show the most expensive book that each customer has ever ordered and doing it with a uncorrelated sub query.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", title, retail
from Customers join orders using (Customer#) join orderitems using (Order#)                 
join books using (Isbn)
where retail =ANY (select max(retail)
                from books join orderitems using (isbn) join Orders using (order#) join Customers using (Customer#)
                group by Customer#)                 
order by  Firstname, Lastname;
```

The inner query shows the max retail of each customer but I'm not sure why with the outer query it shows customers multiple times. I've just started learning SQL and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? Oracle or MySQL? In which table is the `retail` column located? Is `title` a part of `books`?

Comment: This is using Oracle. Title, and retail is in the books table. Customer# and first ,lastname are under customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", title, retail
from Customers join orders using (Customer#) join orderitems using (Order#)                 
join books using (Isbn)
where (Customer#, retail) in (select Customer#,  max(retail)
                from books join orderitems using (isbn) join Orders using (order#) join Customers using (Customer#)
                group by Customer#)                 
order by  Firstname, Lastname;
```

or the way I like to do that, without selecting the same thing twice:

```
select Name, title, Customer#, retail
from (select Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name", title, Customer#,  
             retail, max(retail) over (partition by  Customer#) max_retail
        from books 
        join orderitems using (isbn) 
        join Orders using (order#) 
        join Customers using (Customer#))    
where retail=max_retail             
order by  Firstname, Lastname;
```

Comment: Tyvm this works and  helped me understand different ways of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  Firstname || ', '|| Lastname "Name"
  ,max(retail) "Most expensive book by customer"
from 
  Customers c, Orders o, OrderItems oi, Books b 
where c.customer#=o.customer# 
  and o.order#=oi.order# 
  and oi.isbn=b.isbn
group by Firstname || ', '|| Lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaw here is with your logic, not the syntax. The inner query returns the maximum retail price per customer, and then the outer query returns any joined row that matches one of those prices. Consider the case where you have two customers - customer 1 made to purchases, one for 10$ and one for 20$, and customer 2 that made just one purchase of 10$. The inner query will return 20$ (the max purchase of customer 1) and 10$ (the max purchase of customer 2), and then the outer query will return **all** the purchases in either of these amounts, i.e., all three rows. The "textbook" solution would be to [`rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions155.htm#SQLRF00690) each customer's purchases, and return only the top one per customer:

```
SELECT   name, title, retail
FROM     (SELECT firstname || ', '|| lastname AS name,
                 title, 
                 retail,
                 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer# ORDER BY retail DESC) AS rk
          FROM   customers
          JOIN   orders USING (customer#)
          JOIN   orderitems USING (order#)                 
          JOIN   books USING (isbn))
WHERE    rk = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: As long as OP is not actually using `MySQL` where window functions aren't implemented :)

Comment: @ConsiderMe according to his comments he's using Oracle. I wonder if I should edit the question's tags accordingly, or leave it to the OP to be on the safe side.

Comment: A nice solution. The problem with getting the max of something is, when there are two with the same (price). In your solution you get randomly one of them, my solution shows both. It depends, which is better.

Comment: or I might be wrong. I never use `rank()`. What I said, would at least be true for `row_number()`

Comment: @a.j.tawleed you are wrong - if there are more than one books tied at first place both will have the same `rank()` of `1`, and both would be returned. If you indeed want to return just one of them, `row_number()` may be more appropriate

Comment: Never used rank before, but this worked and was cool to try something different. Thanks!